# Graylog stopped logging exceptions

Tags: graylog2, graylog

We are using graylog along with Gelf4Net and log4net for logging exceptions using GelfUdpAppender.

After deployment, graylog stopped logging exceptions while exceptions are getting logged in a file.

After recycling app pool, graylog start logging exceptions.

Observations: Gelf4Net stopped making UDP requests to the destination server.

What could be the possible cause?

Comment: We had a similar issue https://github.com/jjchiw/gelf4net/issues/18, but at the end it was a misconfiguration (https://github.com/jjchiw/gelf4net/issues/18#issuecomment-97927767) and we have this issue too https://github.com/jjchiw/gelf4net/issues/37

But at the end we still can't find the issue..  :/